# Travelling to rural areas in the US without a car

Tags: usa, public-transport, transportation, rural

My friends will be visiting me in US from abroad, and I'd like to travel with them. We are thinking of travelling across many states. One concern that we have is transportation, because none of us have car/driving license in US. I know there are many public transportation for city to another city, but we would like to travel to remote cottages away from cities as well.

My question is: ***What are the methods of transportation for people in US without a car to visit rural areas?***

I'm looking for a general recommendations/tips on travelling without a car. I'm looking for resources like [Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.com/) or [Uber](https://www.uber.com/), though I know most of Greyhound travel is limited to bigger cities. I'm doubtful about Uber as well, especially in remote areas.

Comment: Train + bicycle.

Comment: @bishop Sadly bike may not be the best option, since we may have bulky luggage (musical instruments,etc). Not very willing to bike during winter, anyways.

Comment: You wrote "none of us have car/driving license in US". Do you have a driving license from your home country? Then it might be valid in the US.

Comment: @dunni Yes we do, though there seems to be a system where they distinguish international license from our home country license. I've also heard that there is an age limit when we rent a car, and we are all below 25. Either case, none of us are comfortable driving interstate because we do not drive very often.

Comment: There is almost no public transportation to and from most Rural areas in most of the US. I’d suggest checking the Amtrak map to see if it covers the places you want to visit. I suspect that you’ll need to rely on trains/buses + cabs.

Answer (score 2):

While Uber/Lyft are generally focused on urban areas, their coverage areas can include fairly rural parts.

[Greyhound](https://www.greyhound.com/en/), [Trailways](http://www.trailways.com/), and other bus lines serve many rural locations on and off the Interstate Highway System through *extensive partner agreements* with local or regional operators.

[Amtrak](https://www.amtrak.com/home/) travels through many rural areas, not being connected to the Interstate system at all.  They also have partner ships with regional Bus operators allowing you to book *combined Rail/Bus itineraries*.

While these are great for getting to/from even very small towns, you may still have to search for a local car service/taxi to reach specific locations such as a remote cottage.